# Why can't I use ratio in this ??

Tags: arithmetic, average, ratio

The Question:

> Average salary of **60** employees is **12000 per month.**
>
> Number of executives is **twice** the no of non-executives.
>
> If average salary of non-executives be 2/5th of the average salary of
> executives then what is the average salary of non-executive employees
> ??

Answer is 6000.

I want to know why this is incorrect:

> salaries in ratio =2:5
>
> then  2x+5x=12000
>
> x=12000/7

Please help me !!
And if anything is wrong let me know,

Thank you .

Comment: This is hard to follow.  How many Executives are there?  How many non-executives are there?  if $s$ is the salary of an exec, what is the salary of a non-exec?  What then is the total salary?  How should that compare to the "average salary of $12000$"?

Comment: @lulu no of executive = 40

Comment: @lulu no of non-executives = 20

Comment: Good, so keep going.

Comment: @lulu no no I have the answer . I just want to know why going with the ratio way is not working

Comment: I don't understand your method.  You appear to ignore the fact that there are $60$ employees in total.

Comment: @lulu look if we have given total of something and ratio associated with it like total salary of a,b is 2000 in ratio 1:3 then we can determine there individual salary like this x+3x=2000 ,x= 2000/4 which is 500 .  I am using this logic but it is not working here .

Comment: @user273747 : look at my solution. In order to avoid to waste yours, you can do in the following way: $\frac{2\cdot X\cdot20+5\cdot X\cdot40}{60}=12,000$ that is $X=3,000$ but in this equation $X$ is half salary of non executives

Comment: If you want to do it this way, then:  suppose there were $N$ employees.  We'd have $\frac 23\times N$ execs and $\frac 13N$ non-execs .  If $s$ is the exec salary then we get $\frac 23\times s +\frac 13\times \frac 25\times s=12000$.  That works.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The problem isn't so much that you ignore the $60$ employees, it's that you ignore the fact that the execs/non-execs are in $2:1$ ratio.  But that clearly matters.

Comment: @lulu yes I was missing that and thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 20 non executives with an average salary $S$ and 40 executives with average salary $2.5 S$

thus

$$\frac{20\times S+40\times 2.5\times S}{60}=12,000$$

$$S=\frac{12,000\times 60}{120}=6,000$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 2):

Well, minimally,  your solution doesn't account for the fact that there are twice as many executives as there are workers.

Knowing that fact ($2W = E), and knowing that there are 60 employees, we know that

$$ W + E = 60 \\
W + 2W = 60 \\
3W = 60 \\
W = 20 $$

, where $W$ is the number of worker bees, so, there are $E = 2W = 40$ lazy tie-wearers.

Okay.  From the first fact, the average salary across 60 employees is \$12,000, so, the total money spent on salaries each month is $\$12{,}000 * 60 = \$720{,}000$.

As you did, we will let the basic salary unit be $x$.  Worker bees get 2 salary units ($2x$), and tie-wearers get 5 ($5x$).

Remembering that there are 40 execs and 20 workers, we can account for all the salary units:

$$ 20 \times 2x + 40 \times 5x = \$720{,}000 \\
40x + 200x = \$720{,}000 \\
240x = \$720{,}000 \\
x = $3{,}000 $$

So, \$3,000 is the basic salary unit.  Each worker makes 2 salary units, or \$6,000, and each exec pulls in \$15,000.  Each month.  \$180,000/yr.

Listen, that's just the way that I saw the problem.  If you saw it another way, and are now aware of your counting mistake, a piece of the puzzle that you didn't account for, great.  Work it out until it makes sense.

It's not that there's one right way to do it, or that you know the "best" way.  It's that you can find a way, and you can check that your answer is correct.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and your time . Now I understand what I was missing . Thank you again.